# Probability density function on a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-function, ceiling-and-floor-functions

**Problem:** The life expectancy $X$ of a lightbulb can be modeled as an exponential distribution with $\lambda > 0$. Every started hour shall be counted fully. Therefore consider $K:=\lceil X \rceil $ and distribution of $K$.

I'm not quite sure I understand the question correctly, so I wanted to ask for some advice concerning the topic. I kind of think of it as a discrete modeled distribution since we are always looking at $\lceil X \rceil $.
So here it would be: $$P(K = t)=P(\lceil X \rceil = t)=P(t-1<X\le t)$$ Is this a correct way of approaching the problem? If yes where do I go from here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $T$? Did you mean $K$? And yes $P(K=t) = P(t-1 < X \le t)$ is correct, although I am unclear on what the problem is asking you to do.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean $K$ not $T$ in the beginning. Yes, indeed,
$$
\mathbb{P}[K=t]
 = \mathbb{P}[t-1 < X \le t]
 = F_X(t) - F_X(t-1).
$$
Can you find the cdf of the exponential distribution?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I did mean $K$, edited that now. Since the cdf for the exponential distribution is defined by $F(t)=(1-e^{-\lambda t})$ for the continuous case, I assume I can just insert that it into this equation?

Comment: @Carlo indeed, you can. After you are done, remember to check if you get a valid distribution by summing over all $t$ to get $1$...